# How to add a searchable dropdown list in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can i add dropdown list to search box?
The problem is that when I search for other users in my project, a list of users is displayed, but the list pushes the content down.

Example:

1. Standart position
   [image: Standart position]
2. When i search other users
   [image: When i search other users]

Stuck of my template code:

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search User" v-model="inputValue" />
    <div v-if="inputValue.length > 0">
      <ul v-for="user in filteredUsers" :key="user.id">
        <li @click="userPageLink(user.id)">
          {{ user.nickname }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

P.S.: filteredUsers is a getter from Vuex.

How do i add a dropdown list to my code?

Comment: Just add `position: absolute` to your div, containing the list.[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/oh0Lgtyr/)

Comment: Thank you very much my friend! I was sleepy and therefore thought poorly and was looking for solution at JS side.